# How to autoplay sound on webpage with html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, audio

I'm building a quiz app, basically, I want a sound to start playing when a user enters the web page to start playing the quiz.

I tried using javascript to activate sound on page load but the browser does not allow it, it says:

> Autoplay is only allowed when approved by the user.

I tried to use jquery to auto click a button to start sound but it does not still work.

```
const themeSound = new Audio("theme.mp3");
themeSound.play();
```

> broswer error: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed
> because the user didn't interact with the document first.

but if I put the function in a button and I press the button the sound plays perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This restriction is placed on you by the browser.

For example, in chrome, autoplay with sound is allowed if:

- User has interacted with the domain (click, tap, etc.).
- On desktop,
  the user's Media Engagement Index threshold has been crossed, meaning
  the user has previously played video with sound.
- The user has added
  the site to their home screen on mobile or installed the PWA on
  desktop.

Disable this feature all together by launching with the autoplay-policy parameter `chrome.exe --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required`.

Source: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes